# How to select value between two tables based on column existence and grouping in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join, grouping, correlated

I'm trying to select a value from one of two tables based on the existence and matching of values in a few columns between the two tables.  It can be looked at as tbl_b is an override table for tbl_a when certain columns match (ndx1, ndx2) and a value exists in the tbl_b val column.  I'm looking for an efficient way to get the proper values (see rules and anticipated results below).    I'm having trouble getting the grouping correctly to get the anticipated results (attempts in fiddle).

I'm currently running on Oracle 19c.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_a (id number, ndx1 number, ndx2 number, val number);
CREATE TABLE tbl_b (id number, ndx1 number, ndx2 number, val number);
INSERT INTO tbl_a VALUES (100, 1, 1, 2000);
INSERT INTO tbl_a VALUES (200, 1, 1, 4000);
INSERT INTO tbl_a VALUES (300, 1, 1, 6000);
INSERT INTO tbl_a VALUES (400, 1, 1, 8000);
INSERT INTO tbl_b VALUES (100, 1, 1, null);
INSERT INTO tbl_b VALUES (200, 1, 1, 10000);
INSERT INTO tbl_b VALUES (300, 1, 2, 40000);
```

```
select *
from tbl_a;
```

| ID | NDX1 | NDX2 | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 1 | 2000 |
| 200 | 1 | 1 | 4000 |
| 300 | 1 | 1 | 6000 |
| 400 | 1 | 1 | 8000 |

```
select *
from tbl_b;
```

| ID | NDX1 | NDX2 | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 1 | *null* |
| 200 | 1 | 1 | 10000 |
| 300 | 1 | 2 | 40000 |

These are the rules I'm trying to implement to get the appropriate values. I'm treating it like tbl_b is an override table for tbl_a (when there are matching ndx1 and ndx2 values and a tbl_b.val exists).

1. If ndx1 and ndx2 exists and match in both tables, take b.val if it exists else go with a.val

    ex.) if a.ndx1=b.ndx1 and a.ndx2=b.ndx2 then nvl(b.val, a.val)
2. If ndx1 exists and match in both tables but ndx2 not in tbl_b then take a.val

    ex.) if a.ndx1=b.ndx1 and b.ndx2 is null then take a.val
3. If ndx1 exists and match in both tables but ndx2 not in tbl_a then take b.val

    ex.) if a.ndx1=b.ndx1 and a.ndx2 is null then take b.val
4. No consideration for b.ndx1 exists where a.ndx1 not exists (tbl_a is driver)

Anticipated Result Table:

| ID | NDX1 | NDX2 | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 1 | 2000 |
| 200 | 1 | 1 | 10000 |
| 300 | 1 | 1 | 6000 |
| 300 | 1 | 2 | 40000 |
| 400 | 1 | 1 | 8000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MvTRW60T)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and then `COALESCE` the columns giving precedence to `tbl_b` over `tbl_a`:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(b.id, a.id) AS id,
       COALESCE(b.ndx1, a.ndx1) AS ndx1,
       COALESCE(b.ndx2, a.ndx2) AS ndx2,
       COALESCE(b.val, a.val) AS val
FROM   tbl_a a
       FULL OUTER JOIN tbl_b b
       ON     a.id   = b.id
          AND a.ndx1 = b.ndx1
          AND a.ndx2 = b.ndx2
ORDER BY id, ndx1, ndx2
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| ID | NDX1 | NDX2 | VAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 1 | 1 | 2000 |
| 200 | 1 | 1 | 10000 |
| 300 | 1 | 1 | 6000 |
| 300 | 1 | 2 | 40000 |
| 400 | 1 | 1 | 8000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_GJgS8p9)

Comment: Thank you.  I didn't think of the coalesce command.  One quick question, it works as you have written, but it seems to behaving backwards from how I would expect in regards to the 'AND a.ndx2 = b.ndx2' clause.  The example of 300, 1, 1, 6000 in tbl_a and 300, 1, 2, 40000 in tbl_b is confusing me.  If we have that clause, how does it include the those records since they don't match (tbl_a ndx2 = 1 and tbl_b ndx2 = 2?  It seems we would need to leave it off so that it would include both?  @MT0

Comment: @DBox It only rows from `tbl_a` and `tbl_b` when the `id`s and the `ndx1`s and the `ndx2`s all match; if they do not match then you will have separate rows, as per the answer and your expected results.